# My axios Post request doesn't work in my Reacat App

Tags: reactjs, express, post, request, axios

I created two very basic applications to study on requests. One is a React app and the other is Express. I am trying to make a POST request from the frontend React application using "axios". The React app listens to port 3000 while the backend Express app listens to 4200. Thus my code is:

React app (front end).This is my App component where index.js leads to:

```
 componentDidMount() {
    
    axios.post("http://127.0.0.1:4200", "hello").then(res =>{
      alert("Sent");
    }).catch(console.error)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>Hello World!</p>
      </div>
    )
  }
```

Express app.js axios part:

```
axios = require("axios");
axios.get("/" ).then(function(){
  console.log("I listened");}
).catch(err=> {
  console.log(err);
});
```

However I got this error from the "inspect" option of the frontend app (localhost:3000)

```
index.js:1 Error: Network Error
    at createError (createError.js:16)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (xhr.js:83)
```

and

```
VM343:45 POST http://127.0.0.1:4200/ net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

Any idea why? Thanks

Comment: Your `express app.js` isn't express at all. Its axios.

Comment: @tkausl It's only partial code. The rest is express. Maybe I should edit what I meant.

Comment: why don't you try express router in express ? https://expressjs.com/en/starter/basic-routing.html check this link... have a look on how express routing works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @vishnusaran said, I used express router and it worked.